# How can i move repo into different origin

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have old repo in server which previous developer has access to it on gitlab.

And he no longer works here and I don't have access to it.

But i have access to server where repo is clone

So how can i clone it to new git repo with my access to it?

Comment: `git remote set-url origin git@the new location.git`

Comment: @LeiYang This will not clone anything, as asked, just update the upstream url

Comment: i think he(previous dev) already cloned, because he said `where repo is clone`

Comment: @LeiYang   im getting `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`     I have added ssh key to my gitlab and to .ssh/authorized keys... Still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Push only master

```
git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:username/new-repo.git master
```

## Push all branches

```
git push --all --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:username/new-repo.git
```

You can also add the `--tags` flag to push your repo tags.

Comment: im getting `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`     I have added ssh key to my gitlab and to .ssh/authorized keys... Still

Comment: thanks.. nvm i pushed through https not ssh and it worked.